# Split Text File based on Strings

Tags: string, powershell, text, split

I want to split a text file into several files by determining the beginning and end of each file by a specific string.
The beginning of the first file is identifiable by the line `"<ca>"`, the end by `"</ca>"`. Now I want to cut and paste the content in between those two strings in a new text file.
Until now I've written this code:

```
$content = Get-Content .\*.txt
{
    if ($f -eq "</ca>") { $c > .\file.txt; }
    if ($f -ne "<ca>" -and $f -ne "</ca>") { $c += $f }
}
```

The second "if" is supposed to delete the "identification strings" from the created file.

I ran into two issues:

- I can only select the end of the text
- all paragraphs from the source file aren't there anymore, the new file consists of just one line with everything in it

The file is a VPN-Configuration and looks like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 448
verify-x509-name
<ca>
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=de
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICzDCCAjWgAwIBAgIJANfh65DfDF45GFSD
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>  
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=de
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
AoGBAN/jBWwRnjNtxJ+bj3U5oKhYjfu33N2dGlM9x5un9YLm9k6pBzhvG
</key>
```

The output looks like that:

```
clientdev tunproto udpremote 448verify-x509-name<ca>Certificate:...
```

(and so on)

Comment: Please clarify what you are attempting to accomplish. The best way to do this would be to provide an example of the initial file, and an example of the final result.

Comment: Why are you use brackets in 2 and 5 line? What is $c, is a short form $content. You dont have iteration, don't have any set-content, any forwarding like >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off doing this with a multiline regex.

```
Get-Content .\vpnconfig.txt -Raw | Select-String '(?sm)<ca>(.+)</ca>' | Select -Expand Matches | Select -First 1 -Expand Value
```

Makes sure you use `-Raw` when using Regex like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked out great for me, exactly as I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as a single string and use a regular expression match for extracting the CA certificate:

```
$config = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.ovpn' -Raw

if ($config -match '(?ms)<ca>(.*?)</ca>') {
    $matches[1].Trim() | Set-Content 'ca.crt'
} else {
    'No CA certificate found.'
}
```

Prior to PowerShell v3 use `Get-Content | Out-String` to get the content of the file as a single string.

Comment: Thank you very much! I modified it a bit and used some of it in Connors Script! Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner to split file by search string on Powershell.

### Split files by content string, run in Powershell:

`$i=0;(gc Testfile.txt -raw) -split '#'|%{$i++;sc Testfile$i.txt -value $_}`

This example splits Testfile.txt to multiple files with incremental number,  Testfile1.txt, Testfile2.txt, etc...whenever the string '#' is found in the original file. The '#'-is also removed in the process.

Quite useful, I found it on the internet and decided to share it.